# How to connect or subscribe to Redux Store without using connect()?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In react application, I have a constant file where I create a object of HTML strings, in these HTML strings I have to pass some dynamic values from the states stored in `store`, below is the structure of my constant file(its a sample structure, actual file has approx 18-20 html string objects):

```
import store from '../store';
let storeState = store.getState();
let dynamic_Data_from_Store = storeState.initAppReducer.clientData;

const HTML_MESSAGES = {
    REQUEST_OPTIONS: "<div>"+dynamic_Data_from_Store+"</div",
    ENQUIRY_OPTIONS: "<div>"+dynamic_Data_from_Store+"</div",
    OTHER_VALUES: "<div>"+dynamic_Data_from_Store+"</div"
}

export default HTML_MESSAGES;
```

In the above code snippet only initial store state will be available but not the updated store state in future. As per documentation, we have to have the component subscribed to redux store to get the updated states through `connect()`

But as you can see that this file is not the component and is created to have the constants defined, then, how can I subscribe this to get the updated state?

Comment: I am not sure why would you do like this? I would recommend to create react component for all (i.e. REQUEST_OPTIONS, ENQUIRY_OPTIONS) etc which are connected to redux store and then just use those components.

Comment: @PrakashSharma I am using these html string constants to insert in db for further usage.. Ofcourse, the ideal way to create UI components is to have individual components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have come up with after reading between the lines of comment by @remix23

In my component, wherever I am going to consume my `HTML_MESSAGES`, I will connect it to store and then replace the defined placeholders with my required store state. For Example:

My Component which consumes my constant file:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import CONSTANTS from '../../../utils/Constants';
import HTML_MESSAGES from "../../../config/html_inserts";

class InsertMessages extends Component {

    createDataMessage = (type) => {
        let msg = '';
        switch (type) {
            case CONSTANTS.REQUEST_OPTIONS:
                msg = HTML_MESSAGES.REQUEST_OPTIONS;
                break;
            case CONSTANTS.ENQUIRY_OPTIONS:
                msg = HTML_MESSAGES.ENQUIRY_OPTIONS.replace('<clientData>', this.props.cliendData);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return msg;
    }

    insertMessages = (type) => {
 let content = this.createDataMessage(type);

let insert = //gql insert query
return insert;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                {this.insertMessages(type)}
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        cliendData: state.initAppReducer.clientData
    };
  };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(InsertMessages);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you can connect a component without using `connect` that won't really help as the store is only accessible at runtime, not at module initialization.

It depends on how you intend to use it but you can make HHTML_MESSAGE a function instead of a plain object:

```
function HTML_MESSAGES(dynamic_Data_from_Store) => {
    REQUEST_OPTIONS: "<div>"+dynamic_Data_from_Store+"</div",
    ENQUIRY_OPTIONS: "<div>"+dynamic_Data_from_Store+"</div",
    OTHER_VALUES: "<div>"+dynamic_Data_from_Store+"</div"
}

export default HTML_MESSAGES;
```

From where you import HTML_MESSAGE (hopefully in a connected component) you will be able to pass dynamic_data to the HTML_MESSAGE **function**

```
HTML_MESSAGE(dynamic_Data_from_Store)
```

Comment: I am using these html string constants to insert in db for further usage and I have given a sample code here, its an object of approximately 18-20 html strings...

Comment: Ok then can you edit your post to add the React code making the call to insert in the DB. I'll edit my answer if I can.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the latest strings then consider creating a function which would fetch the latest redux state and then return the latest HTML strings.

```
import store from '../store';

function getHtmlMsg() {
    let storeState = store.getState();
    let dynamic_Data_from_Store = storeState.initAppReducer.clientData;

    const HTML_MESSAGES = {
        REQUEST_OPTIONS: "<div>"+dynamic_Data_from_Store+"</div",
        ENQUIRY_OPTIONS: "<div>"+dynamic_Data_from_Store+"</div",
        OTHER_VALUES: "<div>"+dynamic_Data_from_Store+"</div"
    }

    return HTML_MESSAGES;
}

export default getHtmlMsg;
```

Now calling `getHtmlMsg` function should return the latest strings everytime.